# Grouping 1 minute data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have millisecond data, I want to group it to 1 min rows how do I do this?

example timestamp: 20150831000700000

Year 2015 month 08 day 31 Timestamp: HHMMSSZZZ where ZZZ is milliseconds.

How do I group this data in 1 min rows?

Comment: convert that into minutes and then compare

Comment: what is the SQL for this convert? do you mean round to 1 min?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to truncate the value to the minute.  One method for doing this in SQL Server converts the value to minutes since the beginning of time and then adding them:

```
select dateadd(minute,
               datediff(minute, '2000-01-01', timestamp),
               '2000-01-01'
              )
```

Note:  Often, this is expressed using `0` instead of a specific date.  However, these functions take integer arguments, so you have to be careful about numeric overflow.  I don't think this is a problem with minutes, but it is a problem with seconds and milliseconds.  In any case, a recent "reasonable" date is a safe precaution (and the functions also work with negative values).

Also, this assumes timestamp is stored properly as a date/time data type.  If it is a string, then just use `left(timestamp, 12)`.  If it is numeric, you can implicitly or explicitly convert to a string and still use `left()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATEPART(n)` to get the minute, so your grouping should be something like:

```
GROUP BY DATEPART(n, your_timestamp_column)
```

However if you do not limit your data to a certain day/hour, you might receive unexpected results. It is not really clear what you want to achieve